# Regex to extract URL domain name with a dash in it using Node.js

Tags: node.js, regex

I am trying to extract just the websites name from a URL and all the stackoverflow answers haven't led me anywhere.

My URL is in the following format:

https://order-dev.companyname.com

I just want to extract `order-dev` from the URL.

Comment: What language are you using? Not only can this materially affect which RegExp conventions you can use, but the community may also be able to point you in the direction of something a bit more robust than a RegExp for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that. I'm using Node.js

Comment: Are you using ```express``` with ```nodejs``` or is it just ```nodejs```

Comment: @NishantShamVispute Typescript/Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work for me `(?<=\/\/)(.*?)(?=\.)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an **express framework** with your node app then it is easy to get a domain/list of subdomains directly from the incoming request..

**Using Express Framework**

```
req.hostname() // returns 'example.com'
req.subdomains() // return ['ferrets', 'tobi'] from Host: "tobi.ferrets.example.com"
```

**For plain NodeJS**

All Incoming request will contain the following header `origin` which can be extracted using the following `request.headers.origin` in any functions where you handle your incoming request [MDN LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin)

Answer (score 0):

In most JavaScript engines (i.e., most browsers (excluding IE) and Node) you can also use [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) for this, specifically [`URL.host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/host) combined with [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
const siteUrl = 'https://order-dev.companyname.com';
const myURLObject = new URL(siteUrl);
const subdomain = myURLObject.host.split(".")[0];
console.log(subdomain); // "order-dev"
```

Comment: O wow! Did not know this. Apparently I have to retrieve a environment variable and append a string to it from within a config file. I'll def keep this solution in my tool bag. Thanks